# Limit cpu usage to one core

Tags: linux, limit, ulimit, concurrency

I want to run a server with user-written scripts. But these scripts should only use one core (which should be the one with the lowest usage because there will be many concurrent scripts). Also I need to limit time and RAM for them.

Is there an easy way to achieve this, or do I need to check which core has the lowest usage and assign it to it via e.g. ulimit?

Comment: Why?  If two of the scripts can run at the same time, and there are two cores that are idle, why would you not use them?

Comment: @psusi you misunderstood. they should run concurrent. but each script should run on only one core. well script isn't also the correct word. they can be written in perl, python, ruby, java, scala, c and c++...

Comment: @DanCornilescu thanks yeah, that answers my question. what does the protocol say, delete this question or let it be?

Comment: Each program only *can* run on a single core, unless it is multi threaded, which is unusual for scripts ( C/C++ programs, even even Java, are not scripts ).

Comment: @psusi yeah, poor wording in my sie, sorry...